Not able to pass even a text constant to PHP using XMLHttpRequest
I was trying to pass a Javascript variable to PHP through POST xmlhttprequest but even a text literal is not working.
I checked the answered question passing a javascript variable to PHP with xmlhttprequest but it did not work in my case. Below is my code
HTML/Script
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en">
    <button type="button" id="saveButton">Save Button</button>
    <script> document.getElementById('saveButton').addEventListener('click', function() {

var inst_a = new XMLHttpRequest(); inst_a.open("POST", "check_name-indev02.php");

inst_a.send("inputname=dummy");

inst_a.onreadystatechange = function() { 
if (inst_a.readyState == 4 && inst_a.status == 200) 
     {console.log(inst_a.responseText);}       
     }
 });

 
PHP
<?php if (isset($_POST['inputname']))
    {echo "set";} else {echo "not set";}  ?> 

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. The console always returns "not set" which means the constant "dummy" never reached the PHP. The actual page does a lot of other things including Jquery calls but only this part isn't working. So I am including only the identified issue.

Yes, I have mentioned this in the question. But I skipped a few lines of code. So it wasn't working. Should I delete this question.

If the question is already answered in another question, SO policy is to close the question as a duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates

Because you were not properly reporting your POST data type, so $_POST was not filled.
var inst_a = new XMLHttpRequest();
inst_a.open("POST", "check_name-indev02.php");

// Need this line
inst_a.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

inst_a.send("inputname=dummy");

Setting HTTP header Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded  can tell PHP to parse your POSTed body.

Oops. I removed that line thinking it is only when whole html needs to be parsed, not for simple text . Now it is working with variables and other functionality too.  Thank you so much...

@user3467434 but it's not simple text that you're sending, it's structured form data. This content type has nothing to do with html either. If you were sending html there's a different content-type for that :-)

You need to set the Content-Type header. Here's how you could do that:
 document.getElementById('saveButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
        var inst_a = new XMLHttpRequest();
        inst_a.open("POST", "check_name-indev02.php", true);
        
        // You need this line to fix you issue
        inst_a.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        
        inst_a.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (inst_a.readyState == 4 && inst_a.status == 200) {
                console.log(inst_a.responseText);
            }
        };
        inst_a.send("inputname=dummy");
    });

The setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); line is crucial because it tells the server that you're sending form data (similar to what a regular HTML form does).
